# help in cmake for qt ros

Tags: ros, cmake, qt4

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I have a problem and i don't know what is this, if anybody can help i appreciate it, this is my cmake and i get this warning, how can i solve it?
warning ==>

```
    CMake Warning at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:409 (message):
      catkin_package() include dir
      '/home/vahid/catkin_ws/src/jur_segmentation/jur_gui_segmentation/build/devel/include'
      should be placed in the devel space instead of the build space
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
      CMakeLists.txt:22 (catkin_package)

CMAKE ==>

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
project(jur_gui_segmentation)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
             qt_build
             roscpp
             sensor_msgs
             message_generation
             cv_bridge
)

find_package(OpenCV 2.4.9 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${PROJECT_NAME})

add_service_files(FILES jur_segmentation_service.srv)

generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES sensor_msgs)

catkin_package(
#    CATKIN_DEPENDS
#        qt_build
#        roscpp
#        sensor_msgs
#        message_runtime
#        cv_bridge
#    DEPENDS
#        opencv
)

## Qt
rosbuild_prepare_qt4(QtCore QtGui)

file(GLOB QT_FORMS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ui/*.ui)
file(GLOB QT_RESOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} resources/*.qrc)
file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_MOC RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS include/jur_gui_segmentation/*.h)

QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(QT_RESOURCES_CPP ${QT_RESOURCES})
QT4_WRAP_UI(QT_FORMS_HPP ${QT_FORMS})
QT4_WRAP_CPP(QT_MOC_HPP ${QT_MOC})

file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS src/*.cpp)
qt4_automoc(QT_SOURCES)

## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_FORMS_HPP} ${QT_MOC_HPP})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY launch/
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch
        PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186964/help-in-cmake-for-qt-ros/) by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-07-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrzej Pronobis](https://answers.ros.org/users/13016/andrzej-pronobis/) on 2014-07-20**:
I started seeing this warning myself some time ago and it's due to the MOC compiled files ending up in the build space not the devel space. However, in your case there seems to be another problem that you are using rosbuild commands in your cmakelists in a catkinized workspace.

**Comment by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on 2014-07-21**:
Thanks for tip about rosbuild, I've changed my cmake and i've added qt without any rosbuild macro, by the way, how we can solve this warning, what was your solution?

**Comment by [Andrzej Pronobis](https://answers.ros.org/users/13016/andrzej-pronobis/) on 2014-07-22**:
No solution so far unfortunately. This warning appears for any package using QT and MOC, including the standard ROS hydro packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[there](http://answers.ros.org/question/67244/qtcreator-with-catkin/) is a discussion about same problem

---

Originally posted by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) with karma: 72 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrzej Pronobis](https://answers.ros.org/users/13016/andrzej-pronobis/) on 2014-07-22**:
Is that the same problem indeed? I cannot see any reference to the warning there?

**Comment by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on 2014-07-22**:
Yes, because when i compile code from qtcreator or run cmake alone, i get this warning, but with running catkin_make, there is not any warning. they didn't speak directly about my warning but the problem is same as me.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-08-03**:
In my case I get the warning when running catkin_make.